# Is it possible to use Cassandra as a LRU cache

Tags: database, caching, cassandra, distributed-caching, lru

I would like to store key-value pair in Cassandra and have entry Automatically deleted in LRU fashion when a fixed storage size is reached.

Is it possible to do this using Cassandra, if so what would be the best way to do it.
If not is there any other distributed storage system that would support this use-case while not having to keep all data in memory.

Comment: Are you asking about deleting based on reaching a size threshold, where size is >> available memory size?  That's an unusual use case.  Anyway, with Cassandra you may run into tombstoning issues because of large delete traffic (queue-like semantics).  Other solutions such as Redis or Memcached are better designed for this, but they are supposed to be RAM-only.

Comment: I was more thinking of size as number of key or maximum disk size!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, no, Cassandra does not support LRU out of the box.

You could, if you really wanted to, build a LRU layer in your app on Cassandra to accomplish the same effect. This could be done several ways, but generally you'd want to maintain a separate index of the cache objects along with stats/timestamps and have your app purge objects as appropriate. Even then, disk space wouldn't be a good upper limit due to the nature of how Cassandra stores its data and manages updates, deletes, etc.  Cassandra doesn't free storage immediately on a Delete, rather it sets a tombstone and the old data is removed later ([About Deletes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html)).

One advantage to building a custom caching layer (i.e. in Cassandra) would be that you could move beyond simple LRU eviction and ensure that more expensive objects and or objects that are used more frequently (but not recently) are weighted heavier so that they remain in the cache longer even if they might be purged by LRU.  Whether this would be useful or not would depend completely on your specific use case. But again, Cassandra can get bloated by a lot of data churn and one would need to ensure that the cluster is properly tuned and getting its routine maintenance.

In reality most would deploy Memcache (or similar) to support this use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeb! Any recommendation for the case where data I need to store is bigger than memory and therefore Memcache would not work?

Comment: How big are the cache objects? Are individual cache objects bigger than available memory? Or a large percentage of memory?

Comment: At the point that objects don't fit in ram, or take up a significant portion of it, you can shard (split) the object into smaller chunks across more than one box (memcache cluster). If you have to cache them whole you'll end up writing them to disk. How you do it doesn't really matter. Cassandra, Mongo, etc or serialized objects written/maintained straight out of your app. A quick Google search shows a few disk based cache tools in a variety of languages.

Comment: I would suggest twitter fatcache https://github.com/twitter/fatcache Cassandra have issue with delete and it's hard to maintain a distributed LRU list.

Comment: I saw that once a good while back, and had totally forgotten about it. It's perfect for this use case.

Comment: Also using Cassandra as queue is an anti-pattern since the storage format is not handling delete very efficiently http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra can be used as LRU, you just need to use TTL or manage the removal yourself.

New data is always appended. The removed data is only marked as deleted and is physically removed during compaction. You might need to tweak the compaction.

The advantage of Cassandra is that data is persisted the moment it comes in, you don't have to fit all data into memory except extreme use cases, you can use replication not to lose data, and you can access it from multiple languages. Beware that new data may be not immediately available.

A more lightweight approach is Redis.